# How can I set a photo in the chartjs-plugin-data labels v2.1.0 plugin?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I use the 'chartjs-plugin-data labels v2.1.0' plugin, to create a wheel of luck, you need to replace the text with img in the labels column, how can this be done?

In regular JS, the labels line has the value '2', '3', and so on, then I want to shove img
How can I solve this problem? Need your help soon

```js
const spinWheel = document.getElementById("spinWheel");
const spinBtn = document.getElementById("spin_btn");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const spinValues = [
    { minDegree: 31, maxDegree: 60, value: "Ноутбук игровой MSI Katana GF76 12UD-263RU" },
    { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 30, value: "Lush3 + Ridge x 1 + Микрофон HyperX Quadcast S" },
    { minDegree: 61, maxDegree: 90, value: "Беззеркальная камера Canon EOS R50 Body" },
    { minDegree: 331, maxDegree: 360, value: "Lovense Webcam + Domi 2" },
    { minDegree: 301, maxDegree: 330, value: '"Капуста"' },
    { minDegree: 271, maxDegree: 300, value: '"Картошка"' },
    { minDegree: 211, maxDegree: 240, value: "Apple iPhone 15" },
    { minDegree: 241, maxDegree: 270, value: '"Морковь"' },
    { minDegree: 181, maxDegree: 210, value: "Cougar Throne – кресло для геймеров" },
    {
        minDegree: 151,
        maxDegree: 180,
        value: "Сертификат ВБ",
    },
];

const size = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var spinColors = ["#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032"];

let spinChart = new Chart(spinWheel, {
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    type: "pie",
    data: {
        labels: ['<img src="/img/11.png">', "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: spinColors,
                data: size,
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        animation: { duration: 0 },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: false,
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            datalabels: {
                rotation: 90,
                color: "#ffffff",
                formatter: (_, context) => context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex],
                font: { size: 24 },
            },
        },
    },
});
const generateValue = (angleValue) => {
    for (let i of spinValues) {
        if (angleValue >= i.minDegree && angleValue <= i.maxDegree) {
            text.innerHTML = `<p>Поздравляем, вы выиграли: <br> ${i.value} ! </p>`;
            spinBtn.disabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
};
let count = 0;
let resultValue = 101;
spinBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // spinBtn.disabled = false;
    // text.innerHTML = `<p>Желаю Удачи!</p>`;
    let randomDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (355 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    let rotationInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
        spinChart.options.rotation = spinChart.options.rotation + resultValue;
        spinChart.update();
        if (spinChart.options.rotation >= 360) {
            count += 1;
            resultValue -= 5;
            spinChart.options.rotation = 0;
        } else if (count > 15 && spinChart.options.rotation == randomDegree) {
            generateValue(randomDegree);
            clearInterval(rotationInterval);
            count = 0;
            resultValue = 101;
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.1.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <canvas id="spinWheel"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="spin_btn">spin_btn</div>
<div id="text">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that chartjs-plugin-datalabels is not prepared to work with images.

If there isn't any specific reason why you are using that plugin, you can use [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://github.com/DavideViolante/chartjs-plugin-labels) which seems to better suit your current needs.

Here is your spin wheel with all the labels having the same image (chartjs logo). If you want to change any image or the size of the images you can do so changing the plugin options.

```js
const spinWheel = document.getElementById("spinWheel");
const spinBtn = document.getElementById("spin_btn");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const spinValues = [
    { minDegree: 31, maxDegree: 60, value: "Ноутбук игровой MSI Katana GF76 12UD-263RU" },
    { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 30, value: "Lush3 + Ridge x 1 + Микрофон HyperX Quadcast S" },
    { minDegree: 61, maxDegree: 90, value: "Беззеркальная камера Canon EOS R50 Body" },
    { minDegree: 331, maxDegree: 360, value: "Lovense Webcam + Domi 2" },
    { minDegree: 301, maxDegree: 330, value: '"Капуста"' },
    { minDegree: 271, maxDegree: 300, value: '"Картошка"' },
    { minDegree: 211, maxDegree: 240, value: "Apple iPhone 15" },
    { minDegree: 241, maxDegree: 270, value: '"Морковь"' },
    { minDegree: 181, maxDegree: 210, value: "Cougar Throne – кресло для геймеров" },
    { minDegree: 151,maxDegree: 180,value: "Сертификат ВБ" },
];

const size = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var spinColors = ["#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032", "#303032"];

let spinChart = new Chart(spinWheel, {
    type: "pie",
    data: {
        labels: ['1', "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'My first dataset',
                backgroundColor: spinColors,
                data: size,
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: { duration: 0 },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: false,
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            labels: {
                render: 'image',
                images: [
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                    { src: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg', width: 32, height: 32 },
                ]
            },
        },
    },
});
const generateValue = (angleValue) => {
    for (let i of spinValues) {
        if (angleValue >= i.minDegree && angleValue <= i.maxDegree) {
            text.innerHTML = `<p>Поздравляем, вы выиграли: <br> ${i.value} ! </p>`;
            spinBtn.disabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
};
let count = 0;
let resultValue = 101;
spinBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // spinBtn.disabled = false;
    // text.innerHTML = `<p>Желаю Удачи!</p>`;
    let randomDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (355 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    let rotationInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
        spinChart.options.rotation = spinChart.options.rotation + resultValue;
        spinChart.update();
        if (spinChart.options.rotation >= 360) {
            count += 1;
            resultValue -= 5;
            spinChart.options.rotation = 0;
        } else if (count > 15 && spinChart.options.rotation == randomDegree) {
            generateValue(randomDegree);
            clearInterval(rotationInterval);
            count = 0;
            resultValue = 101;
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js-plugin-labels-dv/dist/chartjs-plugin-labels.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <canvas id="spinWheel"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="spin_btn">spin_btn</div>
<div id="text">text</div>
```